# How do I combine 1440 .csv files that each have a heading that needs to be a column?

Tags: python, csv, spyder

Using Spyder.

I need to combine 1440 csv files (one for each minute of the day) that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L8a9.png). The file names are 201703130001_segmentsdump where the last four numbers is hhmm and the file goes up to 201703132359_segmentsdump Each csv file has a heading on the first row that should instead be a column (the time stamp), where each row has the same time stamp for each file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The variables are MapID, SegmentID, elapsed time in seconds, and an irrelevant variable from left to right (as they don't have headers).

I tried this already:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("I:/INRIX and BeMobile/BeMobile/2017-03-13")
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

But it returns with nothing.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I updated the post.